# Open a file with a weird file extension using php

Tags: php, file-io, file-extension

I've got a file with a weird file extension (.dta). When I try to open it with fopen(), it gives me the following error:

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

This file lives on the server, and I don't want to change its extension. I could make a copy of the file, save the copy as .txt, go into it, then delete it, but I was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: the name of a file including the extension has nothing to do with the ability to open it or read it

Comment: I am able to open this file in sublime text, save is as .txt, and open it using fopen(). The file's contents are just text. So php should be able to open it, but it can't.

Comment: How are you using fopen? I'm guessing you're doing something like `fopen('http://mysite/file.dta')` where `fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/file.dta')`  might be more appropriate?

Comment: php is mostly used as a server language, and you said that your file lives on the server, so is the php script in the same server as the file?, if you want help you'll have to give us all the details, the section of the script that opens the file

Comment: If you are to read the file from a web server over HTTP then use "file_get_contents" instead of fopen, furthermore, 404 means that the URL that you have used does not exists, check the URL that you intend to open.

Comment: I bet you're using a relative path to try and open the file up. You need an absolute path to do that. Use `file_get_contents()` instead and tell me what `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` returns.

Comment: I am using an absolute path. file_get_contents() throws the same error. And yes, the php script is in the same server as the file.

Comment: @SpoonNZ, your suggestion worked! Thanks to all for the help.